# When i try to start a server with my MC plugin, it shows me an error

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft

So i have made a plugin that before had invalid plugin.yml, now, it has problem with enabling. It shows me this error:

```
Error occurred while enabling MinererSMP v1.0 (Is it up to date?)
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at com.carter.minererplugin.commands.infocommand.<init>(infocommand.java:12) ~[?:?]
        at com.carter.minererplugin.Main.onEnable(Main.java:10) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:263) ~[server.jar:git-Bukkit-3eb7236]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:343) ~[server.jar:git-Bukkit-3eb7236]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:479) ~[server.jar:git-Bukkit-3eb7236]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R3.CraftServer.enablePlugin(CraftServer.java:480) ~[server.jar:git-Bukkit-3eb7236]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R3.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:406) ~[server.jar:git-Bukkit-3eb7236]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.loadWorld(MinecraftServer.java:426) ~[server.jar:git-Bukkit-3eb7236]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:205) ~[server.jar:git-Bukkit-3eb7236]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.w(MinecraftServer.java:786) ~[server.jar:git-Bukkit-3eb7236]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.lambda$0(MinecraftServer.java:155) ~[server.jar:git-Bukkit-3eb7236]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_281]
```

The plugin actually loads, can be seen in plugins list (/plugins) but seems that just commands don't work. This is main.java:

```
package com.carter.minererplugin;

import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;
import com.carter.minererplugin.commands.infocommand;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin {
    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        new infocommand(this);
    }
}
```

and infocommand.java:

```
package com.carter.minererplugin.commands;

import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import com.carter.minererplugin.Main;

public class infocommand implements CommandExecutor {
    
    public infocommand(Main plugin) {
        plugin.getCommand("info").setExecutor(this);
    }
    
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
        if(!(sender instanceof Player)) {
            sender.sendMessage("You can't run this command from console.");
            return true;
        }
        
        Player p = (Player) sender;
        
        if (p.hasPermission("minerer.use")) {
            p.sendMessage("&lWelcome to MinererSMP!");
            p.sendMessage("--------------------------");
            p.sendMessage("This plugin is currently under heavy development.");
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your error message shows that there is a problem in your `Main` class at line `10`, and another issue at the `infocommand` class at line `12`. You might want to check those out.

Comment: i have checked it, but i dont know what is the problem, i have edited the question

Comment: I posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To register a command, you need `this.getCommand("yourcommand").setExecutor(new YourCommandClass());` in your main class. Don't forget to add `implements CommandExecutor` in your command class in the class opening, such as: `public class YourCommand implements CommandExecutor {}`.

Also, remove the constructor in your infocommand class.

Comment: Where is the constructor located? (im new to this so i don't know)

Comment: Your constructor is the first method, the one with the class's name. It's `public infocommand(Main plugin) {}`. Remove that in its entirety.